# FAILED: ParseException: cannot recognize input near 'exchange' 'string' ',' in column specification

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr, hadoop-partitioning

I am using latest AWS Hive version [0.13.0](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_SupportedHiveVersions.html).

```
FAILED: ParseException: cannot recognize input near 'exchange' 'string' ',' in column specification
```

I am getting the above error when I run the below(create table) query.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test ( 
foo string, 
exchange string,
bar string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/home/hadoop/test/';
```

If I rename the exchange like 'xch' it creates table successfully. Any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error because `exchange` is a keyword used to move the data in a partition from a table to another table that has the same schema but does not already have that partition for details view [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExchangePartition) and [HIVE-4095](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4095).

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this after create statement 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/Amit/xyz.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE tabele_name;